# Four-velocity and the metric tensor

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, velocity, tensor-calculus

The metric tensor $g_{{\mu}{\nu}}$ has this property

$$g_{{\mu}{\nu}}g^{{\mu}{\nu}}=4$$

and the four-velocity, $U^{\mu}=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau}$ which has this property

$$U_{\mu}U^{\mu}=c^2.$$

So does it mean that

$$g^{{\mu}{\nu}}=\frac{1}{c^2}U^{\mu}U^{\nu}=\frac{1}{2c^2}\{U^{\mu},U^{\nu}\}_+~?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define the four-velocity, we need to specify a worldline. This is evident from the definition $U^\mu=dx^\mu/d\tau$, which involves a derivative with respect to proper time $\tau$. The proper time is defined only for a given worldline.

The metric, in contrast, is defined independently of any worldline.

So the answer is no: $g^{\mu\nu}$ is not proportional to $U^\mu U^\nu$. Here's a counterexample:
$$
   g^{\mu\nu}=
\begin{cases}
   1 & \text{if }\mu=\nu=0 \\
   -1 & \text{if }\mu=\nu>0 \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
  U^\mu=
\begin{cases}
   1 & \text{if }\mu=0 \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Working in units where $c=1$, these satisfy $g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}=4$ and $U_\mu U^\mu=1$, and $g^{\mu\nu}$ is not proportional to $U^\mu U^\nu$.

Answer (score 3):

The metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ is a symmetric, ***nondegenerate***, positive definite 2-tensor, which should have eigenvalues $(\pm1,\mp1,\mp1,\mp1)$ in every coordinate system you choose.

The symmetric outer product of a time-like four-vector with itself, on the other hand, hardly can have this property.

Think to the simplest case of Lorentz metric, and a Lorentz transformation that sends you in the COM frame: the 4-velocity will have components $(c,0,0,0)$ and so your matrix $U^\mu U^\nu$ will have 15 entries out of 16 which are null, then it will have determinant zero (i.e. it will not be nondegenerate).